# Solution comparison/choosing for simple remote plist storage

Tags: android, ios, persistence, cloud

This question is to identify solutions and pick up the "Keep It Simple and Stupid" one.

To simplify, I need put one plist file in remote server, and iOS/Android client can download it to local and ask for updates by certain interval. I knew that we could

- 1) build own server to host the plist file and provide simple web
  service for accessing;
- 2) choose one cloud service ?

Any others ? And which is the KISS one ?